# How can I apply css to modal-dialog and how can I fix Circular Dependency Warning

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-bootstrap

I'm using `ngx-bootstrap` modals in my application. I need to access login & signup modals from anywhere in the applcation so I have wrote one service and accessing the modals using that service.

But I'm unable to change the styles for `modal-dialog` in corresponding `component.css` file. And also I'm facing an warning in my local

```
WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/login/login.component.ts -> src/app/signup/signup.component.ts 
-> src/app/login/login.component.ts

WARNING in Circular dependency detected:
src/app/signup/signup.component.ts -> src/app/login/login.component.ts 
-> src/app/signup/signup.component.ts
```

I understand that the above warning is due to I'm using login in signup & signup in login components.

```
app.component.ts
openLogin() {
    this.myService.loginModalRef = 
    this.modalService.show(LoginComponent);
}

login.component.ts
openSignUp() {
    this.myService.loginModalRef.hide();
    this.myService.signupModalRef = 
    this.modalService.show(SignupComponent);
}

signup.component.ts
openLogin() {
    this.myService.signupModalRef.hide();
    this.myService.loginModalRef = this.modalService.show(LoginComponent);
}

modals-service.service.ts
constructor(
    public loginModalRef: BsModalRef,
    public signupModalRef: BsModalRef,
    private modalService: BsModalService
) { }
```

For full code please visit [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axnvhj)

Answer (score 0):

This is my first answer, so I hope it will be helpful to you. ;)

The "modal-dialog"-class does not belong to your login.component.html, therefore no styling can be applied here. 
The "modial-diaolog"'s class styling is set in a bootstrap.css file, as well as in the vendor-prefixes.less file. Maybe you should check those.

The Circular dependency on the other hand results in, as you already figured out, the login component depending on the Signup-component and vice-versa.

Ask yourself: is that really necessary? Wouldn't a single component for sign up and login do the trick? The UI is similiar in both cases and you can just call two different services, if you really need to.
This would get rid off your circular dependency.

Another approach would be to use a service to handle switching between login and signUp. Like a remote switch.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I can change in my custom css too. But I need entirely different styles for both modals (may be same for the login & signup modals). But there are situations like I need somewhat small modal with some styles. Can I get any example to eliminate circular dependency as u said in any of the approaches.